# Are pens and pence homophones?

Tags: pronunciation

I gather from the dictionary that pen is pronounced as /pen/ and pence as  /pens/. Is the plural pens pronounced as /pens/ or /penz/?

Comment: It's pronounced *penz*. Sibilants are normally voiced if they come immediately after a voiced consonant.

Comment: Not exactly. There is a tendency, but not a rule, for voicing to continue from one segment to the next.  _Pence_ is an exception (the final sibilant in _Pence_ is not voiced, though the sound preceding it is), and exceptions like this are not all that hard to find. The plural of _pen_, on the other hand, uses the` {-Z₁}`  [inflection morpheme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), and the sibilants in the allomorphs of this suffix are **always** voiced after voiced sounds.

Comment: "Pence" rhymes with "dense", "immense", or "tense". But "pens" with "hens", or "tens".

Comment: The rule for the pronunciation of the plural suffix *-(e)s* is the same as [the rule for the pronunciation of *-'s*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308046/whats-the-rule-for-pronouncing-s-as-z-or-s)

Comment: For more details about the phonetic realization of the phonemic contrast between word-final /s/ and word-final /z/ in English, see [Are “whores” and “horse” homophones?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342273) (They aren't, and "pens" and "pence" aren't either; the words ending in the phoneme /s/ exhibit something called "pre-fortis clipping")

Comment: @Robusto Well, kinda. Sibilant *suffixes* are normally lenis (in other words notionally voiced) after voiced consonants (or indeed vowels). Consider *fence, else, mince, tense, false* etc

Comment: The ending sounds of _pens_ and _pence_ are much the same as those of _pans_ and _pants_.